# Create a button to hide/show rect and text in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to create a simple list from a data in a box using d3.js and having a button to hide and show the box and his content. I did it but I got 2 different errors:

1) the list starts from item 2 (!) Where is the first one?

2) If I click the button to hide the box the content is still visible! Only box disappear.

Can you help me to fix it?

**jsFiddle**: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uncoke/fvb4nh68/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  },
  
  
  mounted : function() {
    this.start();
  },
  
  methods: {
   start : function(){
    
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 10},
    width = 960 ,
    height = 500 ;
    var active = true;
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height );
    
    var box = svg.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 20)
            .attr("y", 20 )
            .attr("rx", 20)
            .attr("ry", 20)
            .attr("id", "list")
            .attr("height",400)
            .attr("width", 500)
            .style("stroke", "#112233")
            .style("fill", "#DDD")
            .style("stroke-width", 1);
                    
       var items = svg .selectAll("rect")
            .append("g")
            .attr("id", "texts")
            .data(this.todos)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .style("fill", "#f00")
            .attr("x",  50)
            .attr("y", function (d, i) {
              return 80+(i) * 20;
            })
            .text(function (d, i) {
             return (1 + i) + ") " + d.text;
            });

       svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 20+500-10)
            .attr("cy", 20+10)
            .attr("r", 20)
            .attr("id", "closer")
            .style("stroke", "#fdf8fe")
            .style("fill", "red")
            .style("stroke-width", 1)
            .on("click", function (d, a, i) {
                active   = (active) ? false : true,
                newOpacity = active ? 1 : 0;
                console.log(newOpacity)
                d3.select("#list").style("opacity", newOpacity);
                d3.select("#texts").style("opacity", newOpacity);
                    
              });
                    
    
    },
  
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>


<div id="boxList"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues arise from this code here:

```
   var items = svg.selectAll("rect")
        .append("g")
        .attr("id", "texts")
        .data(this.todos)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
```

There is already a rectangle appended, so we are selecting that rectangle. So when we append a `g` to this, we append the `g` with id `texts` to that rectangle. This isn't valid SVG, but also, not what we want. If we want all the `text` elements inside a `g`, we can restructure a bit:

```
 svg.append("g")           // create a `g`
    .attr("id","texts")
    .selectAll("text")     // select all the `text` elements in the new `g`
    .data(this.todos)
    .enter()
    .append("text")      // append child `text` elements to the new `g`
    ...
```

This also addresses the issue of starting the list at item 2. `selection.enter()` creates an SVG/HTML element for every item in the data array for which a corresponding SVG/HTML element does not already exist. Since we selected a pre-existing `rect` with `selectAll("rect")`, the first item in the data array is bound to that rectangle. There is no need to enter an element for the first item in the data array because one already exists - therefore `selection.enter()` does not create an element for the first item in the data array.

*You can also use `selectAll(null)` if you want to make an empty selection in order to enter everything*

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  },
  
  
  mounted : function() {
    this.start();
  },
  
  methods: {
   start : function(){
    
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 10},
    width = 960 ,
    height = 500 ;
    var active = true;
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height );
    
    var box = svg.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 20)
            .attr("y", 20 )
            .attr("rx", 20)
            .attr("ry", 20)
            .attr("id", "list")
            .attr("height",400)
            .attr("width", 500)
            .style("stroke", "#112233")
            .style("fill", "#DDD")
            .style("stroke-width", 1);
                    
          var items = svg.append("g")   
         .attr("id","texts")
        .selectAll("text")   
        .data(this.todos)
        .enter()
        .append("text")    
            .style("fill", "#f00")
            .attr("x",  50)
            .attr("y", function (d, i) {
              return 80+(i) * 20;
            })
            .text(function (d, i) {
             return (1 + i) + ") " + d.text;
            });

       svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 20+500-10)
            .attr("cy", 20+10)
            .attr("r", 20)
            .attr("id", "closer")
            .style("stroke", "#fdf8fe")
            .style("fill", "red")
            .style("stroke-width", 1)
            .on("click", function (d, a, i) {
                active   = (active) ? false : true,
                newOpacity = active ? 1 : 0;
                console.log(newOpacity)
                d3.select("#list").style("opacity", newOpacity);
                d3.select("#texts").style("opacity", newOpacity);
                    
              });
                    
    
    },
  
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>


<div id="boxList"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Your posts are always very interesting. There is a way to get in touch with you? I'm having some trouble with my d3.js project. Now the hide/show button works but lower()/raise() has unexpected behaviour. I would like to show you the whole context to have your opinion. is that possible? My contact is here https://jsfiddle.net/uncoke/fvb4nh68/  Btw Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

1. for the first one set "text" instead of "rect"

   var items = svg .selectAll("text") // not rect
2. use below line inside the circle on click event

   i[0].parentNode.innerHTML = ""

   ```
     var items = svg .selectAll("text")
           .data(this.todos)
           .enter()
           .append("text")
           .style("fill", "#123")
           .attr("x",  50)
           .attr("y", function (d, i) {
               return 80 + (i) * 20;
            })
            .text(function (d, i) {
                 return (1 + i) + ") " + d.text;
            });

     svg.append("circle")
           .attr("cx", 20+500-10)
           .attr("cy", 20+10)
           .attr("r", 20)
           .attr("id", "closer")
           .style("stroke", "#fdf8fe")
           .style("fill", "red")
           .style("stroke-width", 1)
           .on("click", function (d, a, i) {
                  i[0].parentNode.innerHTML = ""

                  var active   = (active) ? false : true,
                  newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
                   console.log(newOpacity)
                   d3.select("#list").style("opacity", newOpacity);                    
               });
   ```